# Return link to button after .off() function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I make changes in WP mobile navigation menu. I used .off('click) function to stop redirects. How can I turn them on when I need that?

```
$('.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children > a').each(function() {
   $(this).off('click');
});

$('.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children > a').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if ($(this).next('span').hasClass('menu-open')) {
      /* $(this).off('click') <-- Turn it on back (return link to button) */
      return;
   } else {
      $(this).next('span').toggleClass('menu-open');
      $(this).next('span').next('.sub-menu').toggleClass('hide',1000);  
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you remove (off) the EventHandler in the first place? Why not keep the click-event-listener and change the class or a custom data-attribute.

A possible solution could be:

Add an active class when needed (`$(this).addClass('active')`) remove the class (`$(this).removeClass('active')`) when you need to disable the item. Make sure you check for the class in the eventlistener using `hasClass`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please accept when this helped you. Or let me know.